# Checking the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^n+n^4}{(-3)^{n^2-n+1}+\ln(n+1)$

Tags: calculus

I have the following series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^n+n^4}{(-3)^{n^2-n+1}+\ln(n+1)}
$$
I'm trying to check if the series is absolutely convergent or conditionally convergent. I tried every possible test I could think of but I could not solve it.
Please show some guidelines on how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

The series is absolutely convergent.
$$
|\frac{e^n+n^4}{(-3)^{n^2-n+1}+\ln(n+1)} <\frac{e^n+n^4}{3^{n^2-n+1}-\ln(n+1)}.$$ Pull out $e^{n}$ from the numerator and $3^{n^{2}-n}$from the denominator. You will get $\frac {e^{n}} {3^{n^{2}-n}} b_n$ with $b_n \to \frac 1 3$. N0w compare the given series with $\sum \frac {e^{n}} {3^{n^{2}-n}}$

Note that $n^{2} -n >n$ for all $n >2$ and $\sum (\frac e 3)^{n}$ is convergent.

Comment: Why does $b_n \to \frac{1}{3}$ and not 0 ? and do we use the first comparison test to determine convergence of the original series?

Comment: @Zappa After pulling out those factors you will get something like $\frac {1+c_n} {3-d_n}$ where $c_n \to 0$ and $d_n \to 0$. [$c_n=\frac {n^{4}} {e^{n}}, d_n=\frac {\ln (n+1)} {3^{n^{2}-n}}$].

Comment: Thank you! very much appreciated